# Convert date in long format to NSDate in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, nsdate

Iam getting date as "1425551087194" its in long format .How can i convert that into NSDate and display normal "mm-dd-yyyy" format.

I have tried following codes and output also added here

method 1:

```
    NSString * timeStampString =@"1425551087194";
    NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString longLongValue];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:_interval];
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString *_date=[_formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",_date);
```

out put is :07.02.47189

Method 2:

```
NSString * timeStampString =@"1425551087194";
NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString longLongValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *_date=[_formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",_date);
```

output is :08.12.47143

Please help 
Expecting output is current date.

Comment: Your `timeStamp` is in milliseconds, but iOS will only manage in seconds (for `NSTimeInterval` and what expects `dateTimeIntervalSince1970:`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
double getDate=1421112600996; // here replace your value
NSTimeInterval seconds = getDate / 1000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
NSLog(@"ans : %@",date);    // your get answer like  ans :  2015-01-13 01:30:00 +0000
```

**another conversion**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];  // here replace your format dd.MM.yyyy
NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
result: 2015-01-13 07:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

except this every thing seems to be correct

```
NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue]; //use double conversion instead of longlong
 NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:_interval/1000];//converting time interval to seconds
```

Comment: the problem is wrong value was getting assigned to `NSTimeInterval`, which is a double value..!

Comment: You also need to divide that value by `1000.0` as `NSTimeInterval`s measure seconds, not milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * timeStampString =@"1304245000";
NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *_date=[_formatter stringFromDate:date];
```